# Cast Google Home response to Chromecast on TV

Tags: android, chromecast, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to create an application that casts the google home response to chromecast. For example when asked from google home. "ok, google show me the recipe for pizza on TV". Google home should cast the instructions for making a pizza on my TV. Very similar to what it does for Netflix.

I haven't seen any tutorials for it or not even sure if API for this is available from Google. They showed the example for the same thing using calendar in this year's Google I/O. 
If you know how to do this or know of a tutorial that can help me with this. Any pointers in right directions will be helpful.

I am also open to using Google Assistant on my phone instead of using Google Home.

Comment: From what I understand, there currently is no exposed Chromecast API through Google Assistant. If/when such a ability becomes available, there should be an announcement.

Answer (score 1):

Although Chromecast integration has been announced, it is not available yet, wasn't clear exactly what this integration would look like, or when it would be available.

Comment: Nope.
Following the announcements section of the discussion group (https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/105684267327487893574/stream/4bf1d398-5af2-4cd3-86fa-c218df8a08cc) is a good way to find out when things change, however.